# Ringcentral Webhooks - caller name shows extention number instead of mobile number

Tags: php, ringcentral-webhooks

We have created Webhook Subscription for getting missed calls.

We are using "/restapi/v1.0/account/~/telephony/sessions?direction=Inbound&missedCall=true" to get all missed calls/voice calls.

Webhook works good as we get all call information but somehow for some number we get only extention value(101) instead of phone number(refer attahced files)

[image]is there any way to get actual phone number instead of extention number?

Comment: try making it as a string instead of number

Comment: How to do it? As we have many number associate with our ringcentral api. If i call to some number i can see actual phone number in instead of extension id. But for numbers it shows extension id instead of actual phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using password based authentication.

You can use JWT authentication instead of password based authentication

and then add following api to get call for each extension(replace second ~ with extension id)

```
"/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/voicemail",
```

alongwith

```
 "/restapi/v1.0/account/~/telephony/sessions?direction=Inbound&missedCall=true",
```